# Cloze test : parallel structure with and

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

[image: I’m confused with 67.]

[image]

**67).**
 I don’t understand why we cannot add noun because there is already verb “ could be “ 
And I just think that ‘5)you’ve been friends...’ doesn’t sound correct to me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that if you don't include a verb in the blank, then the verb from the first part of the sentence applies, and that verb doesn't make sense with the answer you picked.  Your answer would read this way:

> After all, the relationship with Jennifer could be over in a month and with Brenda as a friend for a long time.

In other words, the relationship [with Jennifer] could be two things:

- (a) over in a month, and
- (b) with Brenda [as a friend for a long time].

Or perhaps it's easier to understand this way:

```
After all, the relationship [with Jennifer] could be
  over
    [when?] in a month
and
  with Brenda
    [how?] as a friend
    [how long?] for a long time.
```

Obviously, saying that the relationship with Jennifer could be with Brenda as a friend for a long time doesn't make any sense.

The correct answer indicates that there are two separate sentences here, joined by "and".